# Multi-tenant setup for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, multi-tenant

I want to setup **multi-tenant** support for our Jenkins. Let, we have 5 jobs for two users (GitHub user) in Jenkins and all the 5 jobs are in a single server.

- `user_1` has `j1`, `j2`, `j3` jobs
- `user_2` has `j4`, `j5` jobs

Now,

- `user_1` can see only `j1`, `j2` and `j3` jobs (and don't see `j4` or `j5`)
- `user_2` can see only `j4` and `j5` jobs

when they come in Jenkins.

How can we setup Jenkins for multi-tenant support?

Comment: This looks like a config question rather than a programming question.

Answer (score 3):

For the quickest approach to accomplish what you are describing, follow these steps:

1. Go to "Configure Global Security" and navigate to the "Authorization" tab
2. Use "Role Based Strategy"
3. Give desired access to users
4. Provide desired job level access for users

You can utilize some type of naming convention for your jobs and you can use regular expression to provide access for a set of jobs.

Another option would be to check out some of the Authentication/Authorization plugins available for Jenkins. A popular plugin in this realm is the [Matrix Authorization Strategy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Authorization+Strategy+Plugin) (often combined with Active Directory), though I have not personally used this.